# How can i update state object in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Intial state :

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState(response.pathway.question)
```

Above state i am using to get the first question from object now same object has answer object also and according to answer i need to change above state how can i do this with useState.

change state that i want to accomplish :

```
 setQuestion(response.pathway.answers[item].question)
```

Current nested object :

```
{
 "pathway": {
"question ": "this is first question",
"answers": {
    "Yes": {
        "question": "this question i want to access if user click on yes"
    },
    "No": {
        "question": "this question i want to access if user click on no"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Would you be more specific about what exactly you need. If pathway already has question and answers then what do you need to set in state.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question correctly. You want to change the question according to the current answer.
You can use the useEffect hook to accomplish that. Assuming you want to subscribe to the changes of the variable item.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setQuestion(response.pathway.answers[item].question);
},[item]);
```